# Ajax SubmitButton Yii does not use the url options

Tags: ajax, yii

I have written a `ajaxSubmitButton` in a view named `_form`  called by my `viewcomment` View.

When the browser display the view _form and I over my mouse on the button, I can see that the link is `post/viewComment`  and not `post/newComment1`   as written in my code

```
<div class="row buttons2">
    <?php echo "toto"; ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton(
                    'AjaxSave',
                    Yii::app()->createUrl('post/newComment1'),
                    array(
                        'type' => 'POST',
                        'dataType'=>'json',
                        'success'=>'js:function(data){
                            alert("commentSubmitted");}',
                        'error'=>'js:function(data){
                            alert("comment NOT Submitted");}',  
                        )
        ); 
        ?>
    </div>
```

My action `newComment1` contains the following

```
public function newComment1($post)
    {
        $comment=new Comment;
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='comment-form')
        {

            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
            $comment->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
            if($post->addComment($comment))
            {
                if($comment->status==Comment::STATUS_PENDING)
                    Yii::app()->user->setFlash('commentSubmitted','Thank you for your comment. Your comment will be posted once it is approved.');
                   $this->refresh();
            }
        }
        return $comment;
    }
```

I dont understand why?

Thank in advance for your help

Comment: Can't say you do something wrong, compare your code with this: http://www.codexamples.com/90/chtml-ajaxsubmitbutton/

Comment: Use Firebug to check if the return contains any errors.